# Correct way to do string interpolation when working with parenthesis () in Angular 5 and angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to dynamically assign values to the steps in my Angular Material `mat-expansion-panel`s, and was wondering how I could achieve this, especially on the field `(opened)="setStep(6)"`?

**I have tried the following (and some other formats):**

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === {{stepPermits}}" (opened)="setStep('{{stepPermits}}')" hideToggle="true">
```

And in my .ts file I have a simple assigning of a value for testing:

```
stepPermits = 7;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it quick : you have this

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === {{stepPermits}}" (opened)="setStep('{{stepPermits}}')" hideToggle="true">
```

You should have this

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === stepPermits" (opened)="setStep(stepPermits)" hideToggle="true">
```